# Querying Event Flow with Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

Using: Universal Analytics (analytics.js)

I am currently testing user experience across a site by triggering different events upon pageView. On a given pageView, multiple events may be triggered.

I am interested in determining what events (or sequence of events) may lead to a conversion being triggered. In the frontend, this can be achieved via Event Flow or Goal Flow visualizations. Unfortunately I could find nothing online regarding querying Event Flow specifically.

Is it possible to query Event Flow from the Google Analytics API? If not, are there any workarounds that would allow us to quantify impact from different flows?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a way of doing it with the API.  I want to start by saying i havent tried doing this I am just going on what i would do if i did want to attempt to do this.

The flow apears to start with any of the normal dimensions country for example.  My first idea was the ga:goalpreviousstep1 dimensiosn then i remembered they cant be queried with other dimensions.

I would look into ga:previousPagePath and ga:nextPagePath see what they come back with.  queried along with your goal or event they might give you an idea of what the user was doing.